# Mapping data from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to map some data that I have stored in an array (the screenshot below), but I can't seem to access them. I get two cards (which is right since there are two arrays in the array), but they are nothing is writen in them. Does anyone know why?

```
{this.state.serials.map((number) => (
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>{number.s.l}, {number.s.ta}</Card.Body>
            </Card>
          ))}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

*Edit:
This is what I get if I console.log(number.s):

[image]

Comment: Try this: `<Card.Body>{number.s[0].l}, {number.s[0].ta}</Card.Body>`

Comment: When I try that I get an error - cannot read property 'l' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number.s` is an array

```
{this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? (<Card>
      <Card.Body>{number.s[0].l}, {number.s[0].ta}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
  ) : null
})}
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error - cannot read property 'l' of undefined.

Comment: make sure that number.s has elements with ternery. i will edit the post in second

Comment: if its not working, try to console.log( number.s) and post it here

Comment: I edited the question and added the console.log(number.s)

Comment: have you tried my solution and it didn't work? try also console.log(number.s[0])

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the state `serials` is like bellow

```js
let data = [
  { 
    s: [
      {l: -127, ta: "878", d: [1]}
    ]
  },
  { 
    s: [
      {l: 22.5625, ta: "003", d: [1]}
    ]
  },
];

console.log(data);
```

So to access value which are in key `l` for each item you must perform it like this

```
{this.state.serials.map((number) => (
    <Card>
        <Card.Body>{ (number.s[0]).l }, {(number.s[0]).ta}</Card.Body>
    </Card>
))}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      serials: [
        { 
          s: [
            {l: -127, ta: "878", d: [1]}
          ]
        },
        { 
          s: [
            {l: 22.5625, ta: "003", d: [1]}
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return this.state.serials.map((number) => (
      <p>
        <span><strong>{ (number.s[0]).l }</strong>, { (number.s[0]).ta }</span>
      </p>
    ));
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried that I got an error - cannot read property 'l' of undefined, as in other cases.